# Is there a "best" way to do something in Python

Tags: python

I'm just starting getting into Python - my focus being on using it with Maya and its API - and I've found that when I'm working on something there's, generally, at least 2 or 3 ways to do the same thing that I'm trying to do. For instance:

```
for key, value in locNameConnector.iteritems():
    value = locNameConnector[key]
    cmds.connectJoint(value, key, pm=True)
```

or

```
for name in locNameConnector:
    cmds.connectJoint(locNameConnector[name][0], name, pm=True)
```

now the code is calling specific things in Maya, but my question is, which way is more correct? I feel like the first one is because it's taking advantage of Python's power, while the second one could be written in any language. Is there a more correct way? Is one faster than the other?

Comment: indenting isn't correct, from when I pasted it in, but you still get the idea.

Comment: the indenter hates tabs, i just replaced em with spaces

Comment: The two codes aren't equivalent, and the first is certainly wrong (`value` is assigned in the `for` loop and then overwritten immediately afterwards).

Comment: Thanks msw. I didn't know that.

Philipp - So what would be the correct way? I'm just learning Python, so I'm not being snide I'm genuinely asking.

Comment: We'd better alert the python developers that they have a bug, since there should only be one way to do a given task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of Python's philosophies is:

> There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it.

(You can see a list of these - known as The Zen of Python - by doing `import this` in the Python shell.)

And Python does try and make it so that there really is only one way. But for any language beyond a very basic level of functionality, though, there is always going to be more than one way to do anything non-trivial - that's simply the way programming is. But even when there is more than one way, there is usually one that's regarded as more 'Pythonic'.

As regards your actual examples, they don't seem to be equivalent - the first one is looking up `value` in `l_LegJointConnectors`, the second looks it up in `locNameConnector`. Is that second line in the first example supposed to be there? If not, the first one is very definitely more Pythonic than the second.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in naming. It was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in the naming, as well as that I could remove that second line. :) Definitely still treading the waters with Python, but I'm enjoying it immensely.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually more than one way that fulfills the specification, but often only one correct way. This is in fact the central design principle of Python (as opposed to, say, Perl). In your example, when you need key–value pairs instead of only keys or only values, use `iteritems`.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the principal "Anything that works is good". Asking yourself -which way would suite me/my code/the application best is more than enough.
But hardcore-python-programmers get very angry if they see any python code which is not "pythonic". A good read for that is [here](http://faassen.n--tree.net/blog/view/weblog/2005/08/06/0).

Comment: I understand where you're coming from with that. I just want to make sure that if I'm using a specific language for a specific purpose that I'm doing it the best way that the language has to offer. :) Thanks for the link too. Very interesting read (with examples that I myself am using that are not pythonic - but I'll change that soon). :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague.It definitely depends on what you want to do but there rarely is ever only one way to do something generally and same applies to python. There are ways of doing things that people would refer to as *pythonic* though that is subjective and depends on who is looking at the code. Read up [*zen of python*](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) by Tim Peters a renowned pythonista and author of *timsort* in the standard library to get an idea of some nice ways to write python code.